# Set up of Hyperledger fabric on 2 different PCs

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, distributed-system

I need to run Hyperledger-Fabric instances on 4 different machines PC-1 should contain CA and peers of ORG-1 in containers, Pc-2 should contain CA and peers of ORG-2, PC-3 should contain orderer(solo) and PC-4 should Node api Is my approach missing something ? if not how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you look at the [Ansible driver](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/tree/master/src/agent/ansible) in Hyperledger Cello project to manage deployment across multiple hosts/vms.

In short, you need to establish network visibility across the set of host/vm nodes such that the peer knows about the orderer to which it will connect and so that gossip can operate. The Cello project does this for you with a set of driver options. The Ansible driver seems to have the most promise.

The Ansible driver can provision to a variety of cloud platforms including AWS, Azure, OpenStack and bare metal.