# Hyperledger Fabric add new peers in different machine

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have completed this [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html) and successfully deployed a business network over what it seems to be a generic hyperledger fabric blockchain.
What i want to do now is to create a new peer in diffenrent machine but connected to the same blockchain. Can't find any information. Any help?
Thank you community!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperledger fabric deployment (real network)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378316/hyperledger-fabric-deployment-real-network)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842660/hyperledger-fabric-how-to-set-up-a-distributed-network-of-peer-nodes

Comment: One more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564281/set-up-of-hyperledger-fabric-on-2-different-pcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy hyperledger on a different machine you need to take advantage of docker swarm and overlay network. You can find the guide at 
[Deploying Hyperledger on Multiple Hosts](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f)

for the next question about extending your existing network by adding peers, follow [Extending your network](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start looking at the hyperledger fabric documentation
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
You will need to understand about a hyperledger fabric network topology. There are many things you need to understand in order to understand how to configure a peer correctly and join it to a channel. The build your first network section will take you through creating a fabric network from scratch.